# How to append XML data in a Python List?

Tags: xml, list

I am creating a python list. I need to append xml data as a list element

The below syntax did not work. How to append xml data type into python list?

```
list.append(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
<name>A Song of Ice and Fire</name>
<author>George R. R. Martin</author>
<language>English</language>
<genre>Epic fantasy</genre>
</book>)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: If i execute the above command., getting Synatx error

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-2631622618353913>", line 3
    list1.append(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try this and see if it does what you want it to do:

```
mylist = ["some random element"]
#note: don't call your list "list"; it's a keyword and shouldn't be used as a variable name

mylist.append("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
<name>A Song of Ice and Fire</name>
<author>George R. R. Martin</author>
<language>English</language>
<genre>Epic fantasy</genre>
</book>""")
mylist
```

Output:

```
['some random element',
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<book>\n<name>A Song of Ice and Fire</name>\n<author>George R. R. Martin</author>\n<language>English</language>\n<genre>Epic fantasy</genre>\n</book>']
```